# select username from different table where id matches in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I need to get the user name from `Login`table, the comments come from `Report_Comments`table that has a FK `UserID`that is the FK of `LoginID` in the `Login` table.

So if `UserID` is 1 it represents `LoginID`1.

With this set up I know wish to get the `Username` from `Login`table and display it in my view (where it says"user name here").

I cant think how to do it correctly, I am think of a query along the lines of, select Username from Login where UserID IS LoginID

**Query idea**

```
SELECT `Username`
FROM   `Login` 
JOIN   `Report_Comments` 
WHERE  `LoginID` =  `UserID`
```

Once I have the correct query how would I set this in my code bellow ?

**Model**

```
    function get_comment()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('Report_Comments');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

**View**

```
 <h1>comments</h1>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th><h3>Comment</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Date</h3></th>
            <th><h3>User Name</h3></th>
        </tr>
        <?php if (isset($reports)) :
        foreach ($reports as $row) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->Comments; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->Comment_Date; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>username here</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php else : ?>
        <p>No Comments</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**Controller**

```
function comments()
    {
        $data = array();

        $this->db->where('ReportID', $this->uri->segment(3));

        if ($query = $this->report_model->get_comment()) {
            $data['reports'] = $query;
        }

        $this->template['middle'] = $this->load->view($this->middle = 'comments/comment_view', $data, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your model:

```
$this->db->select('Report_Comments.Comment, Report_Comments.Date, Login.Username')
  ->from('Report_Comments')
  ->join('Login', 'Report_Comments.UserID = Login.LoginID');
$result = $this->db->get();
```

Then `result` will have the comment, the date and the username as well.

Comment: Wow, Nice. Then I just call the username in the view like `<?php echo $row->Username; ?>` ?

Comment: Yup, as long as you pass the result variable that is returned from your model to the controller into the view

Comment: @Beep take a look at the documentation, it is pretty straightforward: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data